# Web Client Software Factory 2008 ASP.NET project migration to dotNET 4.5 64 bit possible?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, migration, enterprise-library, wcsf

I have old Web Client Software Factory project built with VS2008, WCSF 2008 and MS Enterprise Library 3.1
I have to make changes to the project so I migrated the solution to Visual Studio 2012. It compiles fine with .NET 3.5 and runs on IIS 7.5 as 32bit web application (classic mode asp.net v2.0).

Is it possible to migrate such project to .NET 4.5 (64 bit)?

My guess is no. The last version of  WCSF is 2010 and for the MS Enterprise Library is 5.0.
I think they both are built on .NET 3.5

Did anyone try such migration before?
Thanks

Comment: Actually, the latest release of Enterprise Library is version 6 and it does target .NET 4.5.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I will try the version 6 https://entlib.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning to do the same thing for couple of my applications. 
I did checked out on MSDN and the WCSF project discussion on codeplex seems there's no future roadmap for this WCSF.

See:

- [Web Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699511.aspx)
- [Roadmap for 2012 and beyond ?](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/discussions/275037)